# Restful : multiple cases for a same ressource (same api end point ?)

Tags: angular, spring, rest, dto

For example, i have two scenarios for creating a user :

- Created by administrator, without password. The user will have to choose it on activation page.
- Created by the user himself, with password. The activation page won't show password inputs because the password already exists.

The thing is it's the same resource, a user. But depending on who (where) the api is called, the expected behaviour is different.

In one case the DTO should contains the password posted by the user, in the other case it shouldn't.

What should i do ?

- Two api end point with two differents DTO (with and without password) ? But we don't respect the convention that say one end point for creating a given resource
- Same end point but the DTO received will contain the discriminant to know if we want to handle password or not ? If not, password field must be empty ?
- Something else ?

I'm not sure how to do this right.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best strategy for this situation is passing one attribute in the header of the request. With this information, you can create 2 endpoints using the attribute to direct the request.

Ex:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@PostMapping(headers = "X-YOUR-ORIGIN=user")
public ResponseEntity createUserByUser(){
   ...
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@PostMapping(headers = "X-YOUR-ORIGIN=admin")
public ResponseEntity createUserByAdmin(){
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that was possible. Is it safe to use the header X-ORIGIN ? I read this is about cross domain request. I read this header is filled by the browser too. Do I have the control of it in the front ? I'm using angular by the way. Thank you

Comment: You can create another key to your header, I used X-ORIGIN only how an example. But I understand your question and it is a really good question! Sorry for this, I edit my response!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A custom header won't be a problem, that'sg good. Like i commented in the other answer, I wonder about security with these solutions.  In one case it's a public access (user), but in the other case only admin is allowed to access this end point. Do you know how to manage this ? Currently i'm using spring security annotation on the end point. Thank you

Comment: Yes, if you use Spring Security you can use the @PreAuthorize annotation.

Example: @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")

Link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to make one end point, with an optional parameter. Something like:

`@PostMapping
 public ResponseEntity createUser(@RequestParam(name = "userType") String userType){
   //If it's admin, make sure the pwd is set in the dto. Else, it can be null
}`

Comment: It seems to be a clean idea. I wonder how can I secure this. In one case it's a public access (user), but in the other case only admin is allowed to access this end point. Do you know how to manage this ? Currently i'm using spring security annotation on the end point. Thank you

Comment: May be you could check in the matchers if the userType param is specified as "admin" or something. I'm not sure though