# How to handle multiple methods on same api end point with Swagger code generation?

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot, swagger

I'm currently using Swagger to generate services in front side (angular). This services allow me to call my Spring Boot Rest API.

Example in Spring Boot :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/", headers = {"ROLE-ORIGIN=ADMIN"})
public StatusDTO saveUser(@RequestBody AdminDTO dto)

@PostMapping(value = "/", headers = {"ROLE-ORIGIN=PUBLIC"})
public StatusDTO saveUser(@RequestBody PublicDTO dto)
```

I expected to have two methods generated by Swagger, corresponding to these two implementations.

Like :

```
public saveUserUsingPOST1(dto: AdminDTO, ROLE_ORIGIN: string, observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false ): Observable<any> {

public saveUserUsingPOST2(dto: PublicDTO, ROLE_ORIGIN: string, observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false ): Observable<any> {
```

But swagger choose arbitrarily to generate only one of these two. Consequently i can't use the other.

I do things like this in a try to respect Rest good practices, having a single api end point for a same resource.

EDIT : the post which led me to do this :
[Restful : multiple cases for a same ressource (same api end point ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208479/restful-multiple-cases-for-a-same-ressource-same-api-end-point/55213066?noredirect=1#comment97171752_55213066)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking is basically impossible because you are mapping two different methods to the same URI, that's why swagger is unable to decide which one is going to be used on your documentation. maybe you could you add explicit swagger annotations to generate the documentation but you shouldn't have two different methods to the same endpoint on your spring controller.

Furthermore, your methods have different request bodies and headers so they are not the same endpoint and they cannot be mapped to the same URI, at least not in a RESTful way, that's why swagger is choosing one of them and ignoring the other one. 
Not even adding the endpoint swagger info to each method will result on having two endpoints on your swagger generated doc.

Comment: I understand why it seems impossible. But i though having a single end point for saving a given resource was a good practice. Here we want to save a new user. Only the implementation differs depending on the header, but it's still a user. How do you think I should do that ? I added in the original post the discussion which led me on this

Comment: The problem is that the answer on this question may seems to be correct (technically is completely possible) but it is not the RESTful way to do things as you have clarified that you wanted a RESTful solution and I think that tour question is answered, it's not possible to do what you are asking. About your other question is more opinion oriented and we can discuss about it on a chat if you'd like.

Comment: Ok if you have time for this it would be great